# Access For Loop Hide Objects

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to hide/unhide around 30 objects on my form when the user selects certain values from a dropdown menu. I tried the loop below, however I receive the following error: 'Object doesn't support this property or method.' I have this code running on the 'AfterUpdate' of the dropdown menu object.

```
Dim VisibleVisitFields() As String
Dim VisibleVisitFieldlist As String
Dim varVisibleVisit As Variant
VisibleVisitFieldlist = "VisitDate_Event,VisitTime_Event,VisitSite_Event,VisitStaff_Event,VisitMeet_Event"
VisibleVisitFields = Split(VisibleVisitFieldlist, ",")

If (EventType = 3) Then
    For Each varVisibleVisit In VisibleVisitFields
    [Forms]![subFRM_TBL_Event-All in One].Controls(varVisibleVisit).visible = True
    Exit For
Next
Else
If (EventType <> 3) Then
    For Each varVisibleVisit In VisibleVisitFields
    [Forms]![subFRM_TBL_Event-All in One].Controls(varVisibleVisit).visible = False
    Exit For
Next
End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Which line triggers the error? Suspect it is reference to the subform that is flawed. Never seen code like that to loop through an array. Suggest naming subform container different from the object it holds, such as ctrEvent. What is EventType - a textbox/field on the form? Consider code:

```
Dim aryFields As Variant
Dim x As Integer
aryFields = Split("VisitDate_Event,VisitTime_Event,VisitSite_Event,VisitStaff_Event,VisitMeet_Event", ",")
For x = 0 To UBound(aryFields)
    Me.ctrEvent.Form.Controls(aryFields(x)).Visible = Me.EventType = 3
Next
```

Alternative methods not using array:

Set control Tag property then code loops through all controls on form and sets visibility for those that have particular value in Tag.

```
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl in Me.ctrEvent.Form.Controls
    If ctrl.Tag = "something" Then ctrl.Visibility = Me.EventType = 3
Next
```

Another is to give controls similar names, like: Visit1, Visit2, etc. Then code:

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 to 30
    Me.ctrEvent.Form.Controls("Visit" & x).Visible = Me.EventType = 3
Next
```

Advise no spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Comment: Yea it's the reference. Before I had Me.Controls(varVisibleList).visible. But the same error occurred. EventType is the dropdown menu from the form. i'll give your code a try. Thanks

Comment: You want to set visibility for 30 controls? See edits to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over an array of strings.

```
Dim VisibleVisitFields() As String
```

You need to declare the array to contain variants (which can still contain strings)

```
Dim VisibleVisitFields() As Variant
```